# create page with categories of woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create page with all categories from parent category, and for this I'm using this shortCode in my tamplate shop:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[product_categories]' );
```

I can show all categories of my shop, but i want to show all categories of parent category.

I'm reading in google an woocommerce documentation, but with this short-code, generate URL of this category, but i do click in category redirect to home page.

How do i can  to do page of specifies category. For example, if i want enter in category `music` load template with this products...

I need create a function in functions.php ? or if i use shortcode I can?

my actual result it´s:

[image]

and URl for one category it´s, for example:

```
www.mydomain.com/categoria-producto/accessories/
```

But this return to home

I'm noob with WooCommerce. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[product_categories]` shortcode you're using can accept a number of arguments, one of which is parent:

> Set to a specific category ID if you would like to display all the
> child categories. Alternatively, set to “0” (like in the example
> below) to show only the top level categories.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-13

Pass in the current category ID as the parent attribute and your shortcode will only list out child categories.

If you need to get the current category (WP_Term) when you're viewing one of these pages, use `get_queried_object()` / `get_queried_object_id()`.

---

Having re-read your question, it sounds like you may be asking to display products from a given category instead. Should that be the case, use the `[product_category]` shortcode instead.

Example:

```
echo do_shortcode( [product_category category="CATEGORY-SLUG"] );
```

`[product_category]` will default to showing a maximum of 12 products (`limit`).

Comment: thanks for your response. Sorry if my question it´s wrong or i´m not explaining very well. List all my categories, in this moment it´s correct, but when i go to enter in this category, i have one URL but this URL returned me to home, i don´t know how to do that i can go to my correct theme, page